# Write down user input in a text file

Tags: html, input, text, user-input

i tryed it with a basic html code like :

```
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

but then the input is saved like **fname=John&lname=Doe**

I wrote a script in python that gets the file xxx/xxx/display.txt
when i use the basic html input function, the text will get saved as `fname =john & sname=rober`
what i woud need is the string to get saved as `john rober`

how can i write the input down in the txt file without **=** and **&** , and how do i save it in the file, while overwriting everything previus in the txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need your js-code to be server side. I'd reccoment Node.js for that.

Than we need to format the input with js:

```
// Requiring fs module in which writeFile function is defined:
const fs = require('fs');

var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
var fullname = fname + lname;

// data which will write in a file
let data = fullname;

// Write "data" in "file.txt":
fs.writeFile('file.txt', data, (err) => {
    // In case of an error trhow err:
    if (err) throw err;
})
```